# Копирование схемы (с датой) из одной Azure SQL в другую

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, azure, export, azure-storage

Есть Azure SQL дб надо 3 схемы (инкл таблицы и дату) скопировать в другую Azure SQL дб.
Решили перейти с 2ух дб на одну более мощную.
Даты много, около 1ТB. Поэтому в SSMS или BCP не получается очень медленно.
Наверно надо как то в Azure portal, чтобы не копировать дату взад и вперед.

Обе датабейс на одном Azure хосте.

Пример:

- дб source А_DB схемы с11, с12, с13, с14 даты около 1ТБ в 300 таблицах
- дб target B_DB схемы с21, с22, с23, с24, с25

Желаемый резултат:
Надо получить в дб target B_DB после копирования схемы с датой с11, с12, с13, с21, с22, с23, с24, с25

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать. Пока смог только найти как эксп/имп или бэкап/рестор целой дб, но ничего как из 2дб сделать одну

спасибо